# Como parar um for em Elixir?

Tags: elixir

Estou fazendo um loop que vai checar minha lista. O problema é que o loop não para quando eu chego onde quero, aí acaba mostrando tudo que foi verificado.

```
defmodule Tester do 
    def a(list,p) do 
        for x <- list  do 
            if(x == p) do 
                IO.puts "Number #{p} belongs to the list"
            else 
                IO.puts "Number #{p} does not belong to the list"
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Esse é o output quando chamo a função com a lista `[1,2,3]` e um número `3`.

```
The number 3 does not belong to the list
The number 3 does not belong to the list
The number 3 belongs to the list
```

Comment: Já tentou utilizar o comando `break` ou `return`?

Comment: "*não para quando eu chego onde quero*" e onde é o que você quer? Onde deveria estar parando?

Comment: Se a ideia é apenas verificar se `p` está na lista, pode fazer `p in list`. Essa expressão retornará `true` se estiver na lista ou `false` caso contrário.

Comment: @Danizavtz return e break, não tem em elixir até onde sei.

Comment: @LuizF6843  nossa, que linguagem legal!

Comment: @Woss Eu expliquei um pouco mal, vou refazer.

O que eu quero, é que ele verifique se tem o numero dentro da lista. 
       
Certo. porem ao inves dele devolver apenas "o numero esta na lista", ele ta devolvendo tudo que foi verificado,
 ex ["o numero não está na lista',"o numero não está na lista", "o numero está na lista" ]

Comment: Eu consegui arrumar o "problema", com uma ajuda. Valeu ai quem me respondeu! :)

Answer (score 1):

O que você quer fazer é o que chamamos de return early que você pode ler [aqui](https://www.headway.io/blog/how-to-return-early-from-elixir). No paradigma funcional não costumamos usar estruturas de repetições convencionais das linguagens orientadas a objeto ou estruturais, para fazer isso de retornar true ou false caso um número esteja na lista utilizariamos o `Enum.any?/2`.

```
defmodule Tester do
  def evaluate_list(list, value) do
    # Enum.any? recebe dois parâmetros, uma lista e uma função
    # Essa função deverá retornar true ou false, indicando que
    # Aquele ítem da lista foi encontrado
    list
    |> Enum.any?(fn item -> item == value end)
  end

  def main do
    list = [1, 2, 3]
    value = 2

    case evaluate_list(list, value) do
      true -> IO.puts("Number #{value} belongs to the list")
      _ -> IO.puts("Number #{value} does not belong to the list")
    end
  end
end
```

Essa função poderia ser ainda mais curta utilizando a função `Enum.member?/2`.

```
def evaluate_list(list, value), do: Enum.member?(list, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use o [membership operator, ou operador de membresia](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#in/2) ao invés do `for`, que é uma compreensão de lista no Elixir.

```
def a(list, p) do
  if p in list do
    IO.puts "Number #{p} belongs to the list"
  else
    IO.puts "Number #{p} does not belong to the list"
  end
end
```

---

Não aconselho, porém, se realmente quer parar o `for`, o que você pode gerar uma exceção.

```
try do
  for x <- [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1],
    do: if x == 0, do: throw(:break), else: x
catch
  :break -> :break
end
```